# HTML5 mobile app that needs to capture user profile image

Tags: html, mobile

I have a mobile application built with html 5.  I've deployed the mobile application to iphone, android and blackberry using PhoneGap.  The app loads up a list of user profiles via an Ajax call to my web server which has a database of user information.

My database of user information currently lacks user profile images for any of the users.  **How do I allow a user to associate their user profile on the mobile app with a profile image of themselves?**

My current challenges are:

- I can't seem to get html5 file upload button to work on the iPhone
- a friend told me to try authenticating with linkedin, then ask for their linked in profile image.   This can be done via of a concept of "childbrowser" on ios devices.  But he claims there are some challenges (i think in terms of a good user experience) with android and blackberry?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com)?  Your users would have to set up their profile picture on the site, then they provide you a link to their chosen avatar from the Gravatar website.  It doesn't require any authentication to use.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone browser lacks most of the file related APIs.

Anyway I have had enough problems with File APis to recommend the solution that @saluce is probably your best bet. Use a web service whenever possible to avoid having to deal with files as much as possible and for this particular use case, the gravatar solution is a good bet.